# groupPolicyConfigurations/{groupPolicyConfigurationId}/updateDefinitionValues can't update configuration with API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to update my Microsoft Intune Configuration using Microsoft Graph API.

For this I am using Postman. I have set up an app registration to assign the needed permissions and retrieve an access token. This is working in so far that I can read most of my configurations.

Now I am trying to change a configuration using  `POST /deviceManagement/groupPolicyConfigurations/{groupPolicyConfigurationId}/updateDefinitionValues`. ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-grouppolicy-grouppolicyconfiguration-updatedefinitionvalues?view=graph-rest-beta))

Now the problem is when I forming the request according to the docs:

```
{   "added":[],
    "updated":[{
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.groupPolicyDefinitionValue",
      "createdDateTime": "2017-01-01T00:02:43.5775965-08:00",
      "enabled": true,
      "configurationType": "policy",
      "id": "<id>",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-01-01T00:00:35.1329464-08:00"
    }],
    "deletedIds":[]}
```

I get:

```
error code: BadRequest      
            "date": "2020-11-04T19:04:33",
            "request-id": "c66c508b-0f73-4e7f-966a-97bf460818be",
```

I also tried to inspect the requests sent by the Azure Portal when changing the it in the UI and the Graph API request sent by the UI is quite a bit different than the one from the docs:

```
{   "added":[],
    "updated":[{
            "id":"<id>",
            "enabled":true,
            "presentationValues":[],
            "definition@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/groupPolicyDefinitions('<id>')"
      }],
    "deletedIds":[]}
```

and this one returns a HTTP 403 Forbidden I get a

```
error code: BadRequest
            "date": "2020-11-04T19:04:27",
            "request-id": "c70d67bc-b4d4-40cc-b2c9-7d60896f972a",
```

Unfortunately the response does not contain any information on what exactly the issue is and I don't know if there is any logs  where I could find a more detailed error description.
Does anybody have experience with this and knows where I could get the correct payload for the request?

Comment: Could you please share the request id and timestamp for the error that you have got?

Comment: I edited in the request ids and timestamps

Comment: Could you please check if you are in global administrator role or an Intune Administrator role?

Comment: I am running this in application scope. I have assigned the following permission with administrative consent DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWrite.All

Comment: If you are adding application scope that means you are using client credential flow and please try to add Global admin role to that app and give a try.

Comment: I was using this with cliend id and client secret and running it from Postman with the MS Graph Environment. In the app registration I am using for this I did not find a permission for Global admin role. It has the  DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWrite.All permission.

Comment: Permissions are different and Roles are different. According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/role-based-access-control#azure-active-directory-roles-with-intune-access) to access intune data you need to have those roles. You can add the role to an application by going to Azure Active Directory --> Roles and Administrators --> select Global Admin --> Add assignments to your application.